# model space and homogeneous clip space

Tags: rendering, shader

I am reading the book "real-time rendering",at the third chapter,it says:"vertex shader program transforms vertices from model space to homogeneous clip space".what's the meaning of homogeneous clip space and the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, you might have already figured this out. But here it goes anyway.

Model space is the space inhabited (and even defined) by your object. If you have a unit cube, and its coordinate system is aligned with its sides, then the point (0, 0, 0) corresponds to one of the cube's vertices in the model space. This might not be true in world space, where your entire scene is contained, and this cube can be anywhere in there.

A brief explanation can be found [here](http://escience.anu.edu.au/lecture/cg/Revisal/space.en.html).

So basically, different coordinate systems mean different spaces.

Now, your clip space is the unit cube that contains everything that'll be visible upon rendering, where the item closest to the camera will be at z = 0, and the farthest, at z = 1. Since coordinates are given in affine geometry (read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)!), and the cube is normalized, it's called homogeneous.